# Does the creation of virtual machines on a single piece of hardware improve scalability?

Tags: deployment, architecture, virtual-machine, virtualization, devops

Please excuse my ignorance. I don't know anything and am just trying to learn.

I've been thinking and it appears to me that spinning off more virtual machines on a single computer so you can run separate services on each VM instance only creates isolation between those services so that if one VM instance were crash, it wouldn't affect the others.

If the same service were installed on each of the VM's, then it also provides for availability.

But it does not help the scalability of your services because each VM on the same hardware must share the same limited hardware resources such as disk, memory, CPU, and network interface cards.

Am I thinking right? Sorry if this isn't the right forum to ask this sort of a question. If someplace else is more appropriate, please feel free to move it there.

Comment: There are various ways to improve scalability when launching multiple virtual instances on the same hardware. I wouldn't worry about it as long as you guys know what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you, @MattSchuchard. Could you please tell me how I could learn about those ways?

Comment: This is really a question that would generate an enormous SO answer, but still interesting, so I can help some. What virtualization technology(ies) are you using?

Comment: @MattSchuchard, I am not really using any VM software just now though I have in the past used Windows Virtualization / Virtual PC and VirtualBox. The idea came to me while I was recently exploring Windows Azure Virtual Machines.

Comment: Ok, but you wouldn't be running more than one virtual instance on a single cloud instance.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualization is a thing of the post. Now it's all about containerization. I would suggest you to look into Docker and specifically docker-compose

Try visiting https://www.docker.com, and also https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

Hope It helps.

Comment: I am aware of Docker but only cursorily. I am afraid my question is very direct and I am not sure I want to read a ton of documentation to know its simple and straightforward answer. If you could tie your answer to my question, provide some context and a summary of how your suggestion answers my question, that would be helpful.

Comment: In regards to the first part of your question, Docker allows you to run whatever you want better than a VM would. Basically it  does what a VM does without all the overhead involved with a VM. Hence You would be able to spin up a lot  more docker containers than the VM's. Secondly a container in it's own would be isolated but docker-compose allows for the opportunity to  link containers as you need. The other amazing thing is that since there is a lot less overhead, you have pretty much all your resources still with you and you can easily assign resources to services based on what they need.

Comment: Thank you, @AthulKrishna. That's intriguing enough for me. I am curious to take a look at it now.

Comment: Happy to help mate

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Machines have the advantage that you can adjust the parameters of usage. You can change virtual hardware, memory, disk-space and CPU-usage.
This makes the VM scalable related to the needs.
And if the Host-Machine is getting to weak to serve the requirements you can move the VM on another Host-Machine.
If you want to run a server with maximum available resources it's better to do it without VM but with the best hardware you can get / pay because the VM adds an additional level to computing and is using resources too.